# IDE for web project working with distant copy

Tags: html, ide, intranet

We currently have an intranet host on a server (just Html and js project).

contributors do not have a local copy of the project, and modify the code on a regular basis using Expression web. However, a lot of Expression web's features, like link maintenance, do not work if the project is not on a local cache.

Do you know any good web IDE capable of maintaining a web project directly on a server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This IDE may work for you it is biased in the cloud.

https://c9.io/